# CDN (Cloudfront) Cache Invalidation using Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using carrierwave to allow users to upload images with an ability to crop after upload, the issue is the versions get created and CDN catch them instantly that when users crop they don't see changes because the Cloudfront cache has to be invalidated and takes quite a decent time to refresh on its own.

I thought putting version numbers on file names might be a good way to sorta invalidate cache, how to achieve that using Carrierwave?

And is that the best approach?

Comment: How is the cropping being performed? Through Rmagick via CarrierWave?

Comment: The cropping works with no issues, it uses MiniMagick and i can view the cropped images on the server (not through the CDN)

Comment: What I'm asking is, are you doing the cropping independent of the CarrierWave upload process?

Comment: No, it's after upload and default crops are generated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same issue with cloudflare

here my hackish solution: put the updated_at timestamp in a params. Should work with all CDN

```
class AssetUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  def url(options={})
    super.split("?v=")[0]+"?v=#{model.updated_at.to_time.to_i}" rescue super
  end

end
```

Comment: "hackish", but isn't that actually a clean way to do it ?

Comment: It works! But I don't understand. What is this "v" parameter used for? What's going on behind the scenes? Thanks!

Comment: It used to work perfectly! Problem is now I started using carrierwave-backgrounder and it won't work anymore. Any insights?

Answer (score 8):

To make the url trick work on Amazon CloudFront CDN, just remember to enable query string in your distribution. Go to the behavior tab and enable 'forward query strings'.

Comment: spent a couple hours figuring out what's wrong until I read your answer. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

You can find details on how to do it at carrierwave wiki:

https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Create-random-and-unique-filenames-for-all-versioned-files